# Как создать свой WPF контрол в отдельной DLL

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll, controls

Делаю свой контрол, который определён и используется внутри WPF-проекта. Появился второй проект, в котором контрол тоже понадобился. Копипастить туда неправильно, потому что контрол будет ещё дорабатываться. Решил вынести в отдельную библиотеку, но при перемещении кода контрол перестал отображаться. Есть примеры, что это возможно, такие библиотеки есть у Telerik, Syncfusion, XCEED, DevExpress и других.

Как правильно оформить DLL с контролом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В **библиотеке** нужно определить **базовый стиль** для нового контрола чтобы он мог автоматически подхватываться. 
Это делается за пять простых шагов:

1. В статическом конструкторе контрола разместить следующий код

   ```
   DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
           typeof(CustomControl),
           new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl)));
   ```

   Это значит, что если стиль не задан явно, базовый стиль для контрола должен искаться по ключу:

   ```
   {x:Type my:CustomControl}
   ```
2. В файле **AssemblyInfo.cs** разместить следующий аттрибут:

   ```
   [assembly: ThemeInfo(ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly)]
   ```

   **None** - нет стилей для конкретных тем оформления Windows (если есть, заменить на **SourceAssembly**, если они в этой же сборке, или на **ExternalAssembly**, если они в сборках с шаблоном имени **< SourceAssemblyName >.< Theme-Name >.dll**),

   SourceAssembly - базовый стиль контрола находится в текущей сборке.
3. Создать в проекте с контролом папку **Themes**, в которой разместить файл **Generic.xaml** с базовым стилем контрола. Стили для конкретных тем оформления размещаются в файлах с шаблоном имени **< Theme-Name >.< Color-Scheme >.xaml**, например Aero.NormalColor.xaml, Classic.xaml — исключение.
4. Ключи для всех ресурсов должны иметь следующий вид:

   ```
   x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type my:CustomControl}, ResourceId=StringResourceName}"
   ```

   Это нужно для того, чтобы не было совпадений с ключами из других сборок, поэтому обычный строковый идентификатор **StringResourceName** дополняется ссылкой на тип контрола **{x:Type my:CustomControl}** — это обеспечивает уникальность ключа для ресурса.
5. Стиль контрола оформляется так:

   ```
   <Style x:Key="{x:Type my:CustomControl}" TargetType="{x:Type my:CustomControl}"/>
   ```

Comment: +1, не знал о `ComponentResourceKey`.